# How to add rows in table of android 2

Tags: sql-server-2008

im creating an mmorpg database and i have to create a view to view the 5 most popular items that are contained in the characters inventories as well as the number of characters that have them. I thought of using COUNT but i need it to return more than one value. also how would it be possible for me to show the number of characters that have the items as every item is in at least 2 characters inventories.
please help me out, im really lost with this one.

```
    CREATE TABLE charactor
(
    charactorID INT NOT NULL,
    charactorName VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
    teamName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    skill VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    accountID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES account (accountID),
    PRIMARY KEY (charactorID)
)
GO  

CREATE TABLE item
(
    itemID INT NOT NULL CHECK (itemID > 0 and itemID < 9),
    item1 VARCHAR (40) NULL,
    item2 VARCHAR (40) NULL,
    item3 VARCHAR (40) NULL,
    item4 VARCHAR (40) NULL,
    item5 VARCHAR (40) NULL,
    item6 VARCHAR (40) NULL,
    item7 VARCHAR (40) NULL,
    item8 VARCHAR (40) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (itemID)
)
GO

USE mmorpg_project
GO

CREATE TABLE itemQuantity
(
    charactorID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES charactor (charactorID),
    itemID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES item (itemID),
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (charactorID, itemID)
)
GO
```

This is what i have tried....

```
USE mmorpg_project
GO

CREATE VIEW vwPopItems
AS
    SELECT TOP 5 itemQuantity.quantity, itemQuantity.itemID, charactor.charactorID
    FROM itemQuantity
    JOIN charactor
    ON charactor.charactorID = itemQuantity.charactorID
    GROUP BY itemQuantity.itemID
    ORDER BY itemQuantity.quantity DESC
GO
```

but i keep getting an error not allowing me to order by   This is the error.   Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwPopItems, Line 4 Column 'itemQuantity.quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Also im unsure of how i could get the quantity of characters that have item 1 for example.

Comment: sorry about the title. for some reason it wouldnt accept any title i put in so i had to copy one

Comment: Could you post a bit of your table structure and what statement you already tried?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwPopItems, Line 4
Column 'itemQuantity.quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.   This is the error i keep getting but if i take QUANTITY out of the select list than what would i be ordering by